# adding a sin wave to an ecg signal

Tags: matlab, matrix, frequency, noise, trigonometry

I am trying to add a 50hz sinusoidal noise to an ecg signal, 
the data file has a dimension of :  <373046x1 double> in volts and it was recorded over a period of 186.52 seconds

, here is my noise code

```
 freqNoise = 50;    %  My Frequency [Hz]
 amplNoise = 0.25;  %  My Amplitude
 myNoise  = amplNoise*sin(2*pi.*t.*freqNoise);
```

every time I try to add the noise to the data I get the error of "matrix sizes must agree", I know they should but How can I make them agree without modifying the ecg signal

Comment: By modifying I mean effecting the result ,but adding other columns and so is fine I suppose

Comment: It depends on `t`. If you make `size(t)=73046x1`  tou shouldnt have any problem

Comment: the size of t belonging to the sin wave?

Comment: Yes. The only `t` you have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added following line on top of your code:

```
t = 0:186.52/(373046-1):186.52 ;
```

Above vector hold time instants where we want to calculate the value of signal. Length of signal in time is 186.52 and want 373046 samples during time. So separation between two samples is 186.52/(373046-1) seconds.

Comment: Post a little explanation of what each thing means (OP seems a bit confused)

Comment: How did you define this vector?  How did you come up with the beginning, end and quantization interval?

Comment: even with your t, I am still getting the same error

Comment: Please post the error message. I tried the above vector t with your code and it worked for me.

Comment: Please use t' in function, where you are calculating signal value. T is row vector and I thing you need column vector.

Comment: you are right everything goes correct until this point : 
signalNoise = signal + noise;

Comment: Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: please try these command and post results, size(signal)  and size (noise)

Comment: ans =

      373046           1 

and the size noise is :ans =

           1      373046

Comment: please add this line ==> noise = noise'. Hopefully it will solve your problem